# Проблемы с django-google-charts/графиками в Django

Tags: django, графики

Нужно вывести график на Django, за основу беру эту статью - https://habr.com/ru/post/126704/
Задача идентична, вывести количество платежей в указанный период. В базе данных есть данные. 
Но график не выводит количество платежей за указанный период.

```
def view_func(request):
end_date = date.today()
start_date = date.today() - timedelta(days=31)
userStart = Cost_system1.objects.filter(login_id=request.user.username)

# считаем количество платежей...
qsstats = QuerySetStats(userStart, date_field='date', aggregate=Count('id'))
# ...в день за указанный период
values = qsstats.time_series(start_date, end_date, interval='days')

return render(request,'login/template.html', {'values': values})
```

в values возвращается дата и, насколько понимаю, и количество id, но всегда выводит  [datetime,0], хотя не должен выводить 0.
template.html

```
 {% load googlecharts %}

<div id="count_graph"></div>

   {% googlecharts %}
    {% data values "count" %}
        {% col "string" "Date" %}"{{ val|date:"M j" }}"{% endcol %}
        {% col "number" "# of payments" %}{{ val }}{% endcol %}
    {% enddata %}

    {% options %}
        kind: "LineChart",
        options: {
            backgroundColor: "#f9f9f9",
            colors: ["#09f"],
            gridlineColor: "#ddd",
            legend: "none",
            vAxis: {minValue: 0},
            chartArea: {left: 40, top: 20, width: 240, height: 180},
            width: 300,
            height: 240
        }
    {% endoptions %}

    {% graph "count_graph" "count" %} {# используем опции по умолчанию #}
{% endgooglecharts %}
```

Модель:

```
class Cost_system1(models.Model):
date = models.DateField(default = '2000-03-14' )
sum = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
login = models.ForeignKey(User, to_field='username', max_length=50,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
id_category_cost = models.ForeignKey(Cost_category, max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
id_personal_category_cost = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]